# Pagination redirect set in .htaccess file is not working

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm trying to redirect like below but it's not working.

```
http://example.com/page/2 -> http://example.com/item/page/2
```

Below is the source of `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hogehoge\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://hogehoge.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^hogehoge.com/page/(.*)$ http://hogehoge.com/item/page/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hello @himohimo - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Could you expand on "not working" - what are the symptoms that indicate as much? Take a look at the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more tips on writing questions which are received well here =]

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the domain name from `RewriteRule` check. So instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^hogehoge.com/page/(.*)$ http://hogehoge.com/item/page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You need to set:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ http://hogehoge.com/item/page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, once you have done the redirect:

1. Make sure WordPress is responding properly to the `http://example.com/item/page/1` form of URL (this is also possible by doing another internal rewrite back to `http://example.com/page/1` in `.htaccess` or you may do that with WordPress).
2. Clear browser cache to make sure you are not getting the cached version.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the code after deleting the cache. However, it still doesn't redirect to the new page. I think something(plugin or function.php or etc) is preventing from redirecting. Are there any ways to specify it?

Comment: What happens when you go to this URL structure of your site directly from browser: `http://hogehoge.com/item/page/1`?

Comment: >>Fayaz Thank you for your help! I finally managed by myself. The root cause was the pagination of the Wordpress. I changed some setting and it worked.

Comment: Great, I'm glad everything worked out for you :)

Comment: @himohimoI'm facing the same issue. What settings you've changed in pagination?